# Is it possible to calculate values in arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am currently learning how to use arrays in java. After my lesson I was wondering if it was possible to calculate values in arrays. What i mean is if we have:

```
double quantity[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

double Itemprice [] = {3.5, 0.82, 1, 2.27, 0.15};

double total = quantity * Itemprice;
```

If the user enter quantity (2) and Itemprice (0.82).

For example:

```
showInputDialog("enter a quantity");
showInputDialog("enter an Itemprice"); 

showMessageDialog("total is:" + total);
```

Can anyone tell if that type of calculation is possible when using arrays and if yes, how is it supposed to be done?

Comment: Why would you need an array if the user inputs both quantity and price? You can just multiply the two inputs, right?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes you are right but I was just wondering if it is possible. But thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the best way to make it is using a method and passing the values to it, or accessing the values through their index.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with arrays most people often iterate the values inside the arrays within a loop to reach a certain quantity.

Look at this guide on Arrays: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

With your example, an array would not even be necessary a simple input of quantity and price of each item would be enough to satisfy the total.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop to iterate over the two arrays, and for each item multiply the quantity by the corresponding item price. As Jersono says, you'll need to access the elements of the arrays using their index. You'll also need a variable to keep track of the total amount as you iterate over the items.